# ICommandBarItemProps doesn't support focus method

Tags: office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

I'm implementing a command bar with several buttons on it. The buttons are of type ICommandBarItemProps and assigned to attribute "items" of . Now I want to set focus for one of the buttons using componentRef for accessibility purpose, but it says cannot find focus() on IContextualMenuRenderItem (IRefObject is the type of componentRef). I checked the doc for this interface and did not found focus() supported. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/contextualmenu#IContextualMenuRenderItem

How do we set focus on a command bar button with type ICommandBarItemProps?